# Can I animate something with the Transform Panel, without keyframes?

Tags: animation, scripting, transforms

I’m animating a watch. And I would like to make the arm for seconds *jump* 6 degres every second/30 frames (in 30fps).

I could animate it for a minute in the timeline and add a cycles modifier.

But I would think there is an easier way of doing this sort of thing.

Is there a way of writing in numbers (script) in the Transform Panel? Like in After Effects, «Telling» the rotation axis to jump 6 degrees every 30 frames?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, they are called [drivers](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/drivers/usage.html#add-driver).

Click in the transform panel and type `#`. Then enter the expression you want to use. You can use the keyword `frame` for the current frame number.

For your suggestion *6 degrees every 30* we can use math:

```
#floor(frame/30) * radians(6)
```

The property field will turn purple, when a driver has been added. If you click in it again you can edit the expression. (The `#` will remain hidden once the driver has been added.)

Comment: similarly `radians(6) * (frame // 30)`  will tick 6 degrees each 30 frames.